# How to pass params to other screen in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

My React Js skills are very basic,What I want to get is when I click on a category, I show a list of posts of the category selected in a new screen in this case is PostsScreen.

The problem is that i get the itemId null.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

**Categories Screen**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { NavigationActions, DrawerNavigator,  StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import{Dimensions, Button, View, SafeAreaView, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class WGoals extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Categories'
    };

navigateToScreen = (route, params) => () => {
const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: route,
  params: params
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
}

constructor(props)
  {
super(props);
this.state = { 
isLoading: true,
  }
}

  render() {

    return (

<Container style={styles.background_general}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.navigateToScreen('PostsScreen', itemId = '1')} >
                <Text>Category 1</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.navigateToScreen('PostsScreen', itemId = '2')} >
                <Text>Category 2</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
</Container>      
    );
  }
}
```

**Posts Screen**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { NavigationActions, DrawerNavigator,  StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import{Dimensions, View, SafeAreaView, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

export default class Posts extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Posts'
};

  render() {

    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const itemId = params ? params.itemId : null;

    return (

<Container style={styles.background_general}>

<Text>Details Screen</Text>
<Text>itemId: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}</Text>

</Container>

    );
  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change arguments of your function

```
this.navigateToScreen('PostsScreen', itemId = '1')
```

to

```
this.navigateToScreen('PostsScreen', {itemId: '1'})
```